# Is it possible to create common subdomain for all virtualhosts like mail.* for example?

Tags: apache-http-server

I've quite a number of domains on my vps. I configured postfix, and I would like each domain to access rainloop webmail installation. I don't want to create subdomain for each domain, that would consume too much time!

I tried this:

```
# domain: mail.*
# public: /var/www/projects/rainloop

<virtualhost *:80>

      ServerAdmin sandrodz@
      ServerName  mail.*
      ServerAlias www.mail.*

      #DirectoryIndex index.html
      DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/rainloop

      #Allow .htaccess files to work
      <Directory /var/www/projects/rainloop>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
      </Directory>

      #Custom log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rainloop_error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rainloop_access.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, figured it out. But documentation about this is nonexistent!

```
  ServerAdmin sandrodz@
  ServerName  mail.example.com
  ServerAlias mail.*
```

This works. So serveralias supports wildcard.